# Why two equivalent method for computation of the expected value of a Gaussian distribution produces two different results

Tags: probability-theory, matlab

I have the following question about a random simulation that I am doing.

I want to compute
\begin{align}
M_1=E[|Z|] +  E[|Z+a|] 
\end{align}
where $a$ is some fixed constant and $Z$ is a standard normal.

Next, observe that

\begin{align}
  E[|Z+a|]&= \int |z+a| \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-z^2/2) dz \\
&= \int |z| \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-(z-a)^2/2) dz \\
&= \int |z| \exp( az -a^2/2)  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-z^2/2) dz \\
&= E \left[|Z| \exp( aZ -a^2/2)\right]
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
E[|Z|] +  E[|Z+a|] &=  E[|Z|] + E \left[|Z| \exp( aZ -a^2/2)\right]\\
&=E \left[|Z| \left(1+\exp( aZ -a^2/2) \right)\right]\\
&=M_2
\end{align}

I don't see a mistake in the above steps and I think  $M_1=M_2$.

However, if I do a numerical simulation for example for a value of $a=3$ I get different values for $M_1$ and $M_2$. How can this be? Clearly, I am making a mistake somewhere. However, I am not sure where?

Here is the MatLab code that I am using

> a=3;
>
> Z=randn(1,2000);
>
> M1=mean( abs(Z))+  mean( abs(Z+a))
>
> M2= mean(abs(Z).*(1+exp( a*Z-a^2/2)))

and the outputs are

M1 =

```
3.7768
```

M3 =

```
0.8341
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2000 is not enough to sample from the second one. I did 5 million and have consistently observed values close to M1. (The reason there is simply the second way egregiously shifts values around because of that exponential term; it is like both the random variable that is 0 and 2 with probability 1/2 each, and a random variable that takes 1000000 with probability 1/1000000  both have mean 1, but if you don't sample enough, you will not be able to see the difference.)

Comment: I see. Many thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is correct and the expressions $M_1$ and $M_2$ are indeed equivalent; furthermore, they are both equal to $$\operatorname{E}[|Z|] + \operatorname{E}[|Z-a|] = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \left( 1 + e^{-a^2/2} \right) + (2 \Phi(a) - 1)a,$$ where $\Phi(z) = \Pr[Z \le z]$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.